# x86 32 Bit Assembly question

Tags: assembly, x86, 32-bit, intel, macos

I am currently in the process of learning assembly and I was playing around with if statements. My current code is as follows.

```
write:
mov eax, 0x4     
sub esp, 4       
int 0x80         

main:
    ; The message has already been pushed to the stack
mov eax, 4
inc eax
cmp eax, 5
je write
```

If I put the ret at the end of write: then I get a bus error 10 and if I do not I get an infinite loop resulting in a segmentation error. What should I do to make this work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `call` instruction instead of `je` to get into `write`.  `ret` expects the return address to be on the stack, but it won't get pushed if you use a jump to get there!  You're going to have to put `esp` back to whatever it was when you entered the function, too.  Here's a best-guess example based on your code:

```
write:
  mov eax, 0x4
  sub esp, 4       
  int 0x80
  add esp, 4
  ret

main:  ; The message has already been pushed to the stack
  mov eax, 4
  inc eax
  cmp eax, 5
  jne dontwrite  ; skip calling 'write' if eax != 5
  call write
dontwrite:
       ; the rest of the program goes here
```

Comment: @Jjack where do you get the error - your question doesn't provide enough information to give you much more help.

Comment: I mean after it calls the function once.

Comment: I figured out that if I clear the whole stack, it works but then I get a segmentation fault...

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead. No need to call a procedure in your example.

```
main:  ; The message has already been pushed to the stack
  mov eax, 4
  inc eax
  cmp eax, 5
  jne dontwrite   ; Skip Write

  ; Write
  mov eax, 0x4
  sub esp, 4
  int 0x80

dontwrite:
       ; the rest of the program goes here
```

Comment: I'm not real familiar with interrupts, but I can't see any reason you're subtracting 4 from esp (which is the stack pointer). If you're getting seg faults I would think that would be causing it. Try commenting out that line if it's not important in some way.